# Send Javascript info to php and save it on a database

Tags: javascript, php, get

A former co-worker developed an a quiz which sended results to a databse. He was fired but i need to use that code again . I only have the javascript code and i need to recreate the php ( save.php) which saves the info from javascript . Can you help me with the php code or give me a hint . Thaks !

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#answer_a").click(function() { 
    $.get("http://nameOfWebsite/save.php", {test: "1", question: "1", answer: "a" } );
}); 

    $("#answer_b").click(function() { 
    $.get("http://nameOfWebsite/save.php", {test: "1", question: "1", answer: "b" } ); 
});

    $("#answer_c").click(function() { 
    $.get("http://nameOfWebsite/save.php", {test: "1", question: "1", answer: "c" } ); 
});

    $("#answer_d").click(function() { 
    $.get("http://nameOfWebsite/save.php", {test: "1", question: "1", answer: "d" } ); 
});


    });
```

Comment: What kind of hint do you need? You need to know some basic PHP and database stuff to get this done.

Comment: Well, you could ask your boss to actually hire a PHP dev, seeing as you can't do this

Comment: Did you join as a fresher or an experienced candidate? Or is PHP not your field? Only asking because these are just basics in PHP

Comment: well , i suck at backend dev  ( i'm front end ) and i need it now

Comment: is this a radio button?

Comment: @kevinabelita no , it's an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In save.php use $_GET[] to to use the variables and save them on your table

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$test = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['test']);
$question = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['question']);
$answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['answer']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (test, question, answer)
VALUES ('$test', '$question', '$answer')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: @user3604446 please post the code in your answer so that a.) it is preserved for future visitors of SO and 2.) your answer actually looks like an answer.

Comment: @lucasvs i used this but when i tested but it seems isn't working. I've created the table Person ...test varchar (10) , question int (10) and answer varchar(10) . I've clicked on all answers but in database it only shows something like this : test ( is empty ) , question 0 and answer is empty too. Why ?

Comment: @ LuicanAdrian added a empty line ?

Comment: @LuicanAdrian try print_r($_GET) to see if the variables are not coming empty

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_GET[<name>]` to get the values in your php and `mysqli_connect`to insert the data into the table.

Answer (score 1):

You are already on the right track, the next move is in the PHP. You can use this example to get those values. Consider this example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['test'])) {
    $data = array(); // initialize return data holder
    $test = isset($_GET['test']) ? $_GET['test'] : null;
    $question = isset($_GET['question']) ? $_GET['question'] : null;
    $answer = isset($_GET['answer']) ? $_GET['answer'] : null;
    // they should be inside now, now you can go on with mysql inserts

    // just a sample callback value to check if indeed php got it
    $data['test'] = $test;
    $data['question'] = $question;
    $data['answer'] = $test;

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}


?>

<!-- lets say this is an image -->
<button id="answer_a" type="button">Hi im an image</button>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#answer_a").click(function() { 
        $.get("index.php", {test: "1", question: "1", answer: "a" }, function(response){
            var data = $.parseJSON(response);
            console.log(data); // check this in console
        });
    }); 

});
</script>
```

Comment: It's ok if if add this after u say i can go to insert in mysql : 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","u661039426_sym","nuconteaza123","u661039426_sym");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$test = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['test']);
$question = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['question']);
$answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['answer']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (test, question, answer)
VALUES ('$test', '$question', '$answer')";

Comment: @LuicanAdrian did you try that? put `$sql` inside `mysqli_query()`, like: `$query = mysqli_query($sql);` then to check if inserted: `$inserted = mysqli_affected_rows($con);`. this should output likely `1` if it is inserted